# Is there any option to create final method in dart so no one can override it?

Tags: class, dart, oop, inheritance

In Dart every method gets override. In our business logic we don't need our this function will never override by its child classes so how can we make function

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but why would you want this?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Dart has no way to make a virtual method final/non-overridable.
Further, all classes introduce an interface, so someone can implement the same interface without even extending the original class.